# IMAPSize makes sketchy inaccessible files -- how can I access them?

Tags: file, directory, hidden, invisible

I'm using this program IMAPSize to backup an IMAP inbox.  It makes the backup in C:\Program Files\IMAPSize\backup, but somehow the "backup" folder is only visible to the program, and not to Windows Explorer or even Command Prompt!  "Show hidden files" is on.  I've already tried running as Administrator.  When I go to the "select backup folder" option in IMAPSize, the folder-picker indeed shows the backup folder and its subtree, but the folder has a "lock" icon on it.  Windows Explorer lets me create the "backup" folder in the same place, after which the IMAPSize program still sees the entire subtree, but now the lock icon is on the subfolder of the "backup" folder.  Now Explorer can see the "backup" folder but it appears empty to it.  If I move the "backup" folder, these "phantom" contents seem to move with it, i.e. they can be deleted/restored from Recycle Bin.  I've also tried changing file ownership and security settings -- by default the folder has permissions for "TrustedInstaller" -- but nothing helps.  It seems that literally the only program that can view these folders and files is IMAPSize!  What the heck is going on?  How can NTFS files be purely visible to only one single program?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the following:

- You're running Windows Vista or 7.
- [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) is turned on.
- IMAPSize is running under a normal user account and is trying to write to c:\Program Files.

As a result of all of this, Windows is using [file system virtualization](http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2007/04/26/file-system-virtualization.aspx) to transparently redirect IMAPSize's file I/O to a subdirectory of your profile (probably `c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\IMAPSize\backup`).

If you browse to c:\Program Files\IMAPSize in Windows Explorer, you should see a "Compatibility Files" option in the Explorer toolbar that will show you the backup directory under the VirtualStore subdirectory of your profile.